# how to read configuration files on two different machines using tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have tomcat installed on two machines.How can I read the configuration file for the project.
Is a project in Gitlab deployed in two different places?

Comment: two machines ... a single tomcat ???

Comment: I wrote it wrong, sorry. There's only one project. Tomcat will be installed on two machines

Comment: So keep your properties outside war and use that properties manually. Keep different files with different host and port. Go through this link http://www.java2novice.com/spring-boot/load-external-configuration-files/